# Use huggingface transformers without IPyWidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, ipywidgets, deepnote

I am trying to use the huggingface transformers library in a hosted Jupyter notebook platform called Deepnote. I want to download a model through the pipeline class but unfortunately deepnote does not support IPyWidgets. Is there a way to disable IPywidgets when using transformers? Specifically the below command.

```
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")
```

And the error I receive.

```
ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
```

Note: Installing IPyWidgets is not an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to disable transformers logging. Even though it is possible to use [transformers.logging.set_verbosity](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/logging.html#transformers.logging.set_verbosity) to change the log level, it's not possible to set it to `logging.NOTSET` which [is required](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/file_utils.py#L1253) to skip using `IProgress` and `tqdm`. So we need to hack it like this:

```py
import transformers
import logging
transformers.logging.get_verbosity = lambda: logging.NOTSET

# transformers.logging.get_verbosity()
```

After that you should be able to use:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('we love you')
```

Check out [my Deepnote project](https://deepnote.com/project/Huggingface-in-Deepnote-QW4KEXEqTVSsWByFuqll9A) for details ;)